# How to get the right response output from axios after an ajax call with php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, axios

I am making a like feature using PHP, JS, Axios and Ajax for an instagram like app. I am correctly able to start the click eventhandler for the specific a-tag I want to click to like a post. The response I get after my ajax call won't allow me to check for the status of the response. I pass $response['status']="liked" from my php file but the data variable I get with my ajax call doesn't come out right.

I first made the feature with jquery, but wanted to use axios to avoid long loading times with the jquery framework size.

---

I have tried to select the status using res.data['status'] but that doesn't work either. I seem to get an array with the json response combined.

---

```
// this selects the exact like button for the post I want to like using 
// the data attribute id

let btn = document.querySelector("a.like");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    let postId = this.dataset.id;
    let link = this;
    console.log("test");

    axios.post('ajax/likePost.php',{
        postId : postId

    })
        .then (function (res){
            console.log(res);

            if (res.data == "liked") {
                console.log("we zitten ion de liked");

                let likes = link.nextSibling.innerHTML;
                link.children.src = "images/liked.svg";
                likes++;
                link.nextSibling.innerHTML=likes;
            } else {
                console.log("we zitten ion de niet liked");
                let likes = link.nextSibling.innerHTML;
                link.children.src = "images/like.svg";
                likes--;
                link.nextSibling.innerHTML=likes;
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });


    e.preventDefault();
});
```

````
// this is the php file
<?php

# require bootstrap
require_once("../bootstrap/bootstrap.php");

# check if a session is running with the correct email
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    //User is logged in, no redirect needed!
} else {
    //User is not logged in, redirect to login.php!
    header("location: login.php");
}

# connect to the database
$conn = Db::getConnection();

# get clicked post info from database
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
//get the postId
$postId = $data['postId'];
var_dump($data);
# create empty response array
$response = [];

# get user info from database (get user id based on the session cookie email)
$sessionEmail = $_SESSION['email'];
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from user where email = :sessionEmail");
$statement->bindParam(":sessionEmail", $sessionEmail);
$statement->execute();
$currentUser = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$userId = $currentUser['id'];

# check if a record exists in the likes table where the current post's id and current user's id are available
$likeStatement = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) as count from likes where post_id = :postId AND user_id = :userId");
$likeStatement->bindParam(":postId", $postId);
$likeStatement->bindParam(":userId", $userId);
$likeStatement->execute();
$recordAmount = $likeStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

# if 0 records found => insert new record into the likes table with the current post id, user id en a true liked status
if ($recordAmount['count'] == 0) {
    # first like, so set liked_status to 1
    $liked_status = 1;

    # insert new record
    $insertLikeStatement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO likes (post_id, user_id, liked_status) values (:post_id, :user_id, :liked_status)");
    $insertLikeStatement->bindParam(":post_id", $postId);
    $insertLikeStatement->bindParam(":user_id", $userId);
    $insertLikeStatement->bindParam(":liked_status", $liked_status);
    $insertLikeStatement->execute();

    $response['status'] = 'liked';

} else {
    # check if liked status is true or false
    $getLikeStatusStatement = $conn->prepare("SELECT liked_status from likes where post_id = :postId AND user_id = :userId");
    $getLikeStatusStatement->bindParam(":postId", $postId);
    $getLikeStatusStatement->bindParam(":userId", $userId);
    $getLikeStatusStatement->execute();
    $currentLikedStatus = $getLikeStatusStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    # if post is liked (liked_status 1) change status || if post is not liked, change status
    if ($currentLikedStatus['liked_status'] == 1) {
        $liked_status = 0;
        $response['status'] = 'unliked';
    } else {
        $liked_status = 1;
        $response['status'] = 'liked';
    }

    #update record to contain new liked_status
    $updateStatement = $conn->prepare("update likes set liked_status= :liked_status where post_id = :postId AND user_id = :userId");
    $updateStatement->bindParam(":postId", $postId);
    $updateStatement->bindParam(":userId", $userId);
    $updateStatement->bindParam(":liked_status", $liked_status);
    $updateStatement->execute();
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

```

```
// my output in my console when I log the res (response) from the ajax 
// call
array(1) {
  ["postId"]=>
  string(2) "22"
}
{"status":"liked"}
```



I want to get back the status of the like button so I can change the likes number and the image for the button.
````

Comment: have you tried `res.data.status` instead of `res.data["status"]`?

Comment: get rid of that `var_dump($data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP is echoing out more than just the json response.

```
array(1) {
  ["postId"]=>
  string(2) "22"
}
```

is due to the `var_dump($data);`. Try removing that.